# Why can I change this constant object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, constants

asuming that a "const" is constant, I wouldn't have thought that this is possible:

```
const obj = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
};


obj["key3"] = value3;
obj.key4 = value4;
```

Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: A `const` "variable" is a variable that cannot be re-assigned to another value once created. By mutating the object the variable still holds the same reference, so the variable did not change.

Comment: Constant and immutable are two different things. You are expecting `obj` to be immutable

Comment: Why was my question voted down 4 times? Does anybody feels so much smarter?

Comment: @gear Your question is well formulated with a good example, so that should not be the reason of the downvotes. There is only 1 issue with your example, that is the fact that the variables `value1` - `value4` are not defined. Changing them to strings resolves this. But the most likely reason for the downvotes is probably the lack of research. If you searched "JavaScript why can I change a const" using any search engine, you would probably find an answer. I personally don't find the question downvote worthy, but I assume others might disagree.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you aren't actually changing `obj`.  You're just changing a property of `obj`, so it isn't considered like you're trying to change a constant.

Only doing this is problematic:

```
const obj = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
};

obj = 5
```

Comment: Why would this be downvoted? It's the correct answer.

Comment: @Pointy I don't know. 

Comment: Small addition: if you want to make the actual properties of the Object `const`, look into `Object.freeze`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Comment: @divillysausages Oh snap, I didn't know that!  That's really cool.  Thanks for the addition.

Comment: Note that freezing an object is shallow. If the object contains nested objects they are not frozen. eg. `obj = { a: 1, b: { c: 2 } }` then `obj.a = 3` results in an error, but `obj.b.c = 3` is still allowed. (only `obj` is frozen, `obj.b` is not)

Comment: Thank you for the good answer and additional comments!! Can you explain why my question was voted down 4 times? I am quite new to this forum and am a little bit confused.

Comment: @gear It's probably because of lack of research.  Some admin here explained to me once that stack overflow is supposed to be like an encyclopedia.  Before asking a question, one should do research to see if there's already an answer.  This avoids duplicates.  That's partially why the downvote system exists.  Basically, you have a good question, but it's already been asked.